# Can a Blackberry application running in the background be force closed by the user?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I would like to know if a Blackberry application running in the background be force closed by the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is this third party app called Force close which says it can kill third party apps. The link to the appworld is [this](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/39379/?lang=en)

Comment: Do you know from an API level or from an OS level if you can actually close apps?

Comment: Those applications given as examples are unable to close my application.